# javascript regular expression

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I am doing validation using ValidationEngine plugin. But I need to validate a text area where the user should enter minimum 200 words to submit the form. (But its not mandatory field). So how do I customize this plugin. This plugin uses regex to validate the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression to match n words followed by a .! or ? is:

```
/(\w+\s){200,}\w+[.?!]/
```

If you only want 200 words:

```
/(\w+\s){200,}/
```

Also see [Regex to match sentences with at least n words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643429/regex-to-match-sentences-with-at-least-n-words)

Comment: I think he means it has 0 words, or > 200 words.

Comment: Is this tested and working fine..?? When I tested it, the validation was failing even after 200 words also

Comment: just go for the first part: `/(\w+\s){200,}/` if you don't want to match against .?! in the end...

Comment: Yes.. That worked.. What if I need to do validation for total letters/alphabets instead of words here..

Comment: letters are easier! `.{200,}` (which means more than 200 of "anything")

Comment: .200 means?? Is it /.{200,}/ what you mean??I am sorry.. I am just learning jquery and regex:)Does it includes spaces also??

Comment: I got the above thing worked when used /(\w+\s){200,}/.. But it will only accept characters. I want to accept all the  characters including . , etc and then check the word count